# creating a SSIS package with a SQL query to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I have about had it with SQL Server 2012 64 bit!

I am creating a SSIS package with a SQL query to Oracle and trying to put the file into a flat file. I am using the Oracle OLEDB source and a Flat File Destination for the output. Everything works fine locally, but when put on the server and run through SQL Agent I keep getting the Unicode to Non-unicode errors!

The latest drivers are on the server and the 11g client is on my development machine. The types shown in each step show as DT-STR.

I have the exact same source writing to an OLEDB destination just fine. I don't want to have to write these to a table and then pull them back out just to get this to work. Any solutions? And please, no "just add this" responses.

I have tried a data conversion, but get same result. Please supply DETAILED answers as in go here and change this to this. Pictures never hurt. Thanks

Comment: If you are getting the Unicode to Non-Unicode warning, you might want to use DT_WSTR(Supports Unicode), your issue seems a very small one, just something to do with Type conversion. Oracle VARCHAR supports Unicode by default, whereas Microsoft SQL Server/SSIS has VARCHAR/NVARCHAR or DT_STR/DT_WSTR for non-unicode, unicode

Comment: Pretty demanding requests for a free help site! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you need to convert codepages, not datatypes.

Long answer follows:

Step 0: If you're not already using it, I highly recommend that you switch to using the Attunity Connectors instead of stock Oracle OLEDB connector. You can download it for SQL2012 from Microsoft at: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29283

Step 1: Using the Attunity Oracle Source, you can specify a SQL Command as the data access mode, instead of just pointing at a table.

Step 2: You need to determine the exact code page the Oracle server is using, and the exact code page your SQL server is using. For Oracle servers using the UTF-8 character set, this is most likely `AL32UTF8` and for a Windows Server using the default ANSI-1252 char set, the code page is `WE8MSWIN1252`.

Step 3: Write your plsql query and `CONVERT` the codepage of all the columns on the Oracle side. Make sure you use double quotes around the Oracle column names. It should look something like this:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT("Data Source Code",'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252') AS DataSourceCode
    ,CONVERT("Order#",'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252') AS OrderNumber
    ,CONVERT("Invoice#",'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252') AS InvoiceNumber
    ,CONVERT("Item#",'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252') AS ItemNumber
    ,CONVERT("Order Line Type",'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252') AS OrderLineType
    ,CONVERT("Order Status",'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252') AS OrderStatus
    ,CONVERT("Order Date",'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252') AS OrderDate
    ,CONVERT("Invoice Date",'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252') AS InvoiceDate
    ,CONVERT("Ship To Cust#",'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252') AS ShipToCustNumber
    ,CONVERT("Billing Account #",'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252') AS BillingAccountNumber
    ,CONVERT("Sold Qty",'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252') AS SoldQty
    ,CONVERT("Unit Price",'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252') AS UnitPrice
    ,CONVERT("Sales Amount",'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252') AS SalesAmount
    ,CONVERT("Handling Amount",'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252') AS HandlingAmount
    ,CONVERT("Freight Amount",'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252') AS FreightAmount
FROM MYORACLEDB.DIGITAL_SALES_FEED
WHERE "Invoice Date" >= TO_DATE('2018/08/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Step 4: Use this query text as the `SQL command text` in the Oracle Source configuration window.
[image: Oracle Source]

Fun Fact: Oracle will return the column names in ALL CAPS, regardless of your `AS ColumnName` format.

Step 5 (optional): All columns will be returned as strings. You might want to put a `Data Conversion` task in your Data Flow, but if you're just dumping your data into a flatfile, you might not care about the data conversion. I have decimal/numeric and dates in my data set, so I do a conversion before inserting into SQL Server.